# Update a submenu item in a NavigationView populated with Realm Data

Tags: android, realm, navigationview

I am creating a submenu in a NavigationView that is populated with the last three projects the user has worked with.

```
RealmResults<Project> lastestProjectsReaml  = mDB.where(Project.class).findAll().sort("pLastModification", Sort.DESCENDING);
ArrayList<String> recentProjects            = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    recentProjects.add(lastestProjectsReaml.get(i).getpName());
}
for (String value : lastestProjects){
        recentProjectSubMenu.add(value)
}
```

My problem is that the list will not be updated if a new project is created or if one of the latest projects is deleted. Update the list with new projects is not a problem since I can do it manually every time the user creates one. However, when a project is deleted, I don't know how to deal with it since this operation is handled internally by the adapter and not in the activity.

Any idea how could overcome this? 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days breaking my mind to solve this, as soon as I posted the question, the solution came to my mind.

I simply added a changelistener to my RealmResults that will be triggered when adding/deleting projects.

```
RealmResults<Project> userProject = mDB.where(Project.class).findAll().sort("pLastModification", Sort.DESCENDING);
userProject.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Project>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Project> element) {
            setRecentProjectSubMenu(navigationView);
        }
    });
```

A small remark: within setRecentProjectSubMenu, the submenu has to be cleared. `recentProjectSubMenu.clear();`

Comment: You should use `findAllSorted()` instead of `findAll().sort(...)`, but yeah